# $k\cos\beta \sin\alpha-\sin\beta+d\sqrt{1+k^2}=0$ ，Find $\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$k\cos\beta \sin\alpha-\sin\beta+d\sqrt{1+k^2}=0$. Find $\beta$.
$K$ and $d$ are constant.
$d∈[0,\pm1],k∈[0,\pm\infty)$.

This is an equation in a spherical coordinate system.  Where $\alpha$ is longitude and $\beta$ is latitude.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Is $\alpha$ also a constant and, if not, then what is it's relationship with $\beta$ or anything else it depends on? Please update your question text instead of, or in addition to, commenting here.

Comment: @JohnOmielan $\ beta$ is not a constant, it is the argument of the function.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I realize $\beta$ is not a constant. Note I asked about $\alpha$ since you don't say anything about it. If $\alpha$ is not a constant, it must depend on something and, since the only specific non-constant involved is $\beta$, I asked if it depended on $\beta$, but did not intend to imply that $\beta$ is a constant. So, once again, what is $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not constants. $\alpha$ is longitude and $\beta$ is latitude. This is a spherical coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what $\alpha$ is, as well as specifying what $\beta$ is. One final thing is that, since many people don't read the comments, please add this to your question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& A\cos\beta + B\sin\beta \\[10pt]
= {} & \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \left( \frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^s}} \cos\beta + \frac B {\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \sin\beta \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \Big( \sin\gamma \cos\beta + \cos\gamma\sin\beta\Big) \\
& \quad \text{where } \tan\gamma = A/B \\[10pt]
= {} & \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \, \sin(\beta+\gamma)
\end{align}
You have $A=k\cos\alpha$ and $B=-1.$

Comment: Why is there no $\alpha$ in the answer?

Comment: @u3770435 : The difficulty in the equation you started with is that $\beta$ appears more than once, and in two different ways. The point of my posting was to show how to rearrange it so that $\beta$ appears only once. I left the rest to you.

Comment: @u3770435 : The variable $\alpha$ is present in the expression $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\, \sin(\beta+\gamma),$ in that $A=k\cos\alpha.$ The expression I finished with was not intended to be "the answer"; it was intended to be is an equation that can be routinely solved for $\beta. \qquad$

Comment: OK, I see.  thank you very much.  But you seem to have a typo, it should be $A = k\sin \alpha$.